# Отделы диалоговых окон

Tags: windows, окно

Бывают такие диалоговые окна:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как называются такие отделы таких окон, как *Клавиатура* или *Мышь*?

Comment: Что вас именно интересует? Как реализовать такое окно или что?

Comment: Да, нет же. Ну, вот есть элементы окна ползунки,  счетчики. А у таких отделов окон есть свои названия? Вот каким элементом окна является слово *Клавиатура*?

Comment: То, что у вас на скриншоте в левой части, называется дерево (Tree или TreeView), а конкретный элемент дерева является узлом (Node).

Comment: А в правой части *Клавиатура* что такое?

Comment: А справа обычный контейнер (layout, panel, container), который перерисовывает свое содержимое в зависимости от выбранного пользователем узла. Ну или не перерисовывает, а просто один контейнер меняется на другой контейнер после клика на узел слева. Как правило контейнеры могут содержать множество других элементов. Да и само окно - тоже контейнер верхнего уровня.

Comment: Ну, визуально-то этот контейнер разбит на зоны. Правильно?

Comment: Это уже просто визуальная группировка элементов, из раздела дизайна, общего названия вроде не имеет. В WinAPI ее называются GroupBox. В HTML это fieldset. В Java просто рамка BorderFactory вокруг элементов с подписью. На скриншоте это вообще метка (label) + линия.

Comment: Ясно. большое спасибо.

Comment: Я здесь: http://www.5byte.ru/10/0028.php смотрел, но похожего не нашел,

Comment: Удалили один комент.